# Angular: Refresh target on Angular route

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6 here.

I have a form page where user fills up that form and then on save I save the details to the db and then redirect the user to the List page where he sees all the saved records in list form.

I use below code on save to redirect

```
this.router.navigate([`${CONFIG.app}/listAll`]);
```

The issue is when I do the above, it redirects me to list page but has the old list entries, its only when I refresh the page do I see the recently saved entry. Can anyone suggest whats the best way to do auto refresh of the target page.

Thanks

--Updated--

I have the below on my list component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getAllList().subscribe((obj: any[]) => {
      this.allData= obj;         
     });
   }
```

Below is my service:

```
  getAllList(): Observable<{} | any[]> {
   return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(this.url, {})
      .pipe(map(res => this.extractData<any[]>(res)), 
        catchError(this.exceptionService.catchBadResponse));
    }

    private extractData<T>(response: any) {
    if (response && (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300)) {
       throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + response.status);
     }
     return <T>(response || {});
    }
```

Comment: on the page with the list, do you make a call to get the data from the constructor or from `ngOnInit`

Comment: I have shared my code above

Comment: anyone for inputs

Comment: are you able to create a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

pls share listAll components codes. do you use ngoninit for list

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that !
It's JS framework's aim to avoid reloading.
When you get you API response, inject the received data in you component.

Add your component or/and service if you need help to do it.